# Make a gui multi programs installer

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

Please how do I make a multi program installer? I mean I have 3 .exe programs packed in an .ISO file with an autorun.inf, let's suppose the first is CS_1.6_installer.exe CSS_installer.exe and CS_GO_installer.exe I want to make a gui program to make me choose which CS* installer I want to choose?
Is there any program or a programs code source?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is basically a [suite installation](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-creating-suite-installations.html). The link I included shows how to do this with Advanced Installer (Disclaimer: I work on this tool).